# Is Google ID Token's "sub" claim shared between clients?

Tags: google-oauth, openid, google-signin

Simple question. If I use Google authentication and someone else (not related to my project in any way) authenticates the same Google account, does my and their ID token contain the same "sub" claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I registered two different apps under two different Google accounts and it seems that the "sub" claim is identical.

So the answer is "yes".